# How do I create a temporary directory using mktemp in my current working directory?

Tags: tmp, mktemp

I created a pipeline that strings multiple programs together, unfortunately these programs are creating a huge amount of temporary files in the `/tmp` folder and when using large datasets my pipeline crashes because the `/tmp` folder fills up.

How do I export temporary files so that they are created in my current working directory where the pipeline is being run and not in the `/tmp` folder?

Currently I have tried to export the `TMPDIR` env variable to an already created directory `/work` in my current working directory, but the temporary files are still being created in the `/tmp` folder:

```
export TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=/work)
<script>
rm -rf $TMPDIR
```

The programs do not have the option to set different output folders for temporary files created.

Comment: What error message do you get? Please always mention error messages when they are available.

Comment: The error message for the pipeline? It's a typical IOError: No space available on device error that's very common when the /tmp file is full.

Comment: How much space is left on your hard drive (i.e. `df -h . ` )?

Comment: I have two 4TB hard-drives where I do most of the scratch work.

One is completely empty and the other is 50% full. My /tmp directory only has 9gb of free space which is where the problem stems from.

Answer (score 4):

Just change `/work` to `work` if the directory `work` is in your current directory. `/work` means that you have a top-level directory named `/work`. Without the forward slash, it will be a relative directory.

I just tested this code on my computer. No files were written to `/tmp` that I noticed:

```
mkdir work
export TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=work)
ls work
# tmp.AWA4dTERha
rm -rf $TMPDIR
ls work
# --no output--
```

Comment: Great, let me give this a shot!

Comment: Doesn't seemed to have solved the problem. Temporary files still being created in the /tmp directory.

Comment: @System Just updated my answer to include code that I tested.